# How to add delay to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#slides_left').slides({
        generateNextPrev: false,
    play: 5500
    });
});
```

How can I add a .delay() to the function above so that the starting time for the function is not onload rather to a specified time?

sorry for my noobness in jQuery!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use javascript setTimeOut function

```
setTimeout(functionname, 2000); // replace 2000 with your number of millisecond required for delay.
```

Call this setTimeout inside onload.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    // Start after 3 seconds
    window.setTimeout('doSlide()', 3000);
});

function doSlide(){
    $('#slides_left').slides({
        generateNextPrev: false,
        play: 5500
    });
};
```

There is also a pause option for slides().

Comment: while its waiting for 3 seconds for the function to load the slide show images are stacked one on top of another.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#slides_left').slides({
         generateNextPrev: false,
         play: 5500
      });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: while its waiting for 1 second for the function to load the slide show images are stacked one on top of another.
Thanks