# jQuery loop of executions

Tags: jquery, time

Sincerely I didn't know how to write the title. I need to click in a link of each "li" item but every 5 seconds.

I've tried this way:

```
$("li.li-item").each(function() {
  $(this).find("a").click();
  // here any solution provided in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/javascript-wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line
});
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Set Sail Media, but as I explained you it does not work, since I need each link to be click **every** 5 seconds ... but I did the trick based on what you wrote:

```
function liLoop() { 
   if ($("li.li-item:not(.done):first").length == 0) {    
      clearInterval(loopInterval); 
   } 
   $("li.li-item:not(.done):first").find("a").click(); 
   $("li.li-item:not(.done):first").addClass("done"); 
} 
var loopInterval = setInterval(function(){ liLoop() }, 5000);
```