# Function results appears before for loop executes

Tags: javascript

My question is: why function results appears before for loop in browser console? It should run for loop (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), but it run ('cool' and 1!2!3) first, so below I add my code and console result. I'll be very thankful if someone can explain me this behaviour. It is not a duplicate, because, I want to understand how it works, not to make it work. In suggested question there is a solutions to run for loop with setTimeout first, but not explain behaviour completely.

```
// Loops + Closure
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        console.log(i)
    }, i * 1000)
}

//Modules
function CoolModule() {
    let something = 'cool'
    let another = [1, 2, 3]

    function doSomething() {
        console.log(something)
    }

    function doAnother() {
        console.log(another.join('!'))
    }

    return {
        doSomething: doSomething,
        doAnother: doAnother
    }
}

let foo2 = CoolModule()

foo2.doSomething() // 'cool'

foo2.doAnother() // 1 ! 2 ! 3
```

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROkuM.png)

Comment: Because the for loop fires up a bunch of timers that don't output anything until they expire? I'm not sure why you'd expect anything different.

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  `setTimeout` starts off with a delay of 1 second.  The rest of the code runs in less than a second

Comment: Are you possibly confused by what setTimeout does? It doesn't block execution.

Comment: @Amy - if it were obvious, the OP wouldn't be asking. It might be obvious to you and me, but the question is a valid one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/javascript-wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript works by running blocks of code one after the other. So you have one block of code that starts with the `for` loop and ends with `foo2.doAnother()`. But the calls to `setTimeout` don't run the code immediately -- they put new blocks of code in the queue -- the `console.log(i)` blocks. So your code works more like;

1. Put five 'timer' functions in the queue. Each one must wait 1s, 2s, 3s, etc before it's executed, and each must execute after the current block.
2. Execute the 'CoolModule' code.
3. (the code you wrote finishes executing)
4. (wait 1s)
5. run the first instance of `timer()`
6. (wait another 1s)
7. run the second instance of `timer()`
8. etc...

Comment: So, it's special behaviour of setTimeout() which waits everything to execute in block then start its work?

Comment: Yeah -- setTimeout says 'run this function later' -- it puts the function in a work queue. But before it does anything in the queue, it finishes running the rest of the code.