# Javascript How do I wait x seconds before running next line of code?

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout, delay

I would like to be able to make something similar to this:

```
function testFunction() {
    alert("Test");
}

if (x > y) {
    wait(z);
    testFunction();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried placing the part of source code into a setTimeout? `setTimeout(function(){ //this will run after 3 seconds}, 3000);` If you could be more clear with your question and say which section you want to wait or why it might be easier for someone to give you a solid answer.

Comment: @NewToJS is right! Also you can take a look to this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

Can now nicely be done with promises:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}

demo();
```

Comment: Its important to note this requires support for es6.

Answer (score 6):

Please try using the setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

From this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

So for your specific use case:

```
var timeToWait = 3000; // in miliseconds.
function testFunction() {
    alert("Test");
 }

 if (x > y) {
      setTimeout(function(){ testFunction(); }, timeToWait);
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code in the callback function you supply to setTimeout:

```
function stateChange(newState) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (newState == -1) {
            alert('VIDEO HAS STOPPED');
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

From this question: [Javascript - Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/javascript-wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)