# How to add a delay to confirm box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add a delay on the return statement of a confirm box? I have tried using setTimeout but it doesn't work.

My idea is to display a modal for 5 seconds and then take the user to the signout page.

```
<a href='signout.cgi?id=$key' onclick='singOutConfirm()'> Sign Out</a>

 function singOutConfirm(){
      var c = confirm("Confirm Sign Out!");
      var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); 
      console.log(c);
      if(c == true ) {  
         setTimeout(function(){ 
            return c;
        }, 5000); 
      } 
      return c;
```

Comment: I think just remove that last `return c;` because it's running synchronously, so the timeout isn't working as you're expecting. Also, use `===` instead of `==` in javascript, actually, you dont even need an equals, you can just say `if (c) {` because it's truthy

Comment: You can't delay the function with a timeout. It will run until finished. And then the callback will fire. You need to put code in the callback for `setTimeout` that does what you want instead of just returning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Answer (score 0):

You sir, need a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

But two things

1. They are not supported in ie https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises. You might want to use Babel or Typescript to polyfill them. If you don't want to compile you JS consider using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) for promises.
2. Specifically in your example you are expecting to navigate to a URL on click. You are going to want to change the browsers location when the promise resolves. `window.location.href = 'signout.cgi?id=$key'`

---

```
function signOutConfirm (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const c = confirm("Confirm Sign Out!");
  const modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); 
  console.log(c);
  if(c) {  
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = 'signout.cgi?id=$key'
        resolve(c)
      }, 5000); 
    })
  } 
  return Promise.resolve(c);
}

console.time('Signing out')
signOutConfirm()
  .then(c => {
    console.timeEnd('Signing out')
    console.log(c)
  })
```

Comment: For something this simple, adding all of that promise code is overkill. The `setTimeout` function with the `window.location.href` setter in the function is all that is needed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey correct. To specifically solve the issue @pedro has we don't need to use a `promise`. He did however specify in his question "add a delay on the return statement of a confirm box" and going from the example provided he was a little unsure of how to `return` his delayed value. So hopefully by giving a `promise` example it should shed a little light on the issue for him :)