# How to delay a method call after 1 min in angular or rxjs using Delay operator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

HI  here my scenario is i need call a method only after 1 min here i can also set time out but instead is it possible using  delay method like below

```
getMethod(){
 
}


delay(1000,this.getMethod())
```

or any other better approach

Comment: Check delay or debounce time operator in RxJs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line/28173606 possible duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Comment: @Frost these are promises i am trying to achieve it using delay and using delay also i want to call a method

Comment: @NarkhedeTushar how can we add a method  in delay operator ?

Comment: @Madpop you have a promise, when code comes to subscribe promise line you want 1 min delay before subcribing it?

Comment: @Madpop check fiddle https://stackblitz.com/edit/2vhjym?file=index.ts

Comment: @NarkhedeTushar what abut button click ?

Comment: @Madpop you can use button click event there for the delay operator instead of document click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using rxjs and Angular then you probably want to use the RxJs `timer` subject

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
const minute = 1000 * 60;

function helloWorld() {
  console.log('hello');
}

timer(minute).subscribe(helloWorld);
```

If you are looking into what RxJs Subject or Operator you want, try checking the [RxJs Operator Decision Tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) for help.

Comment: ``const minute`` renamed ``const milliseconds`` would probably be clearer, isn't it ?

Comment: No, as `const minute = 1000 * 60;` is one minute in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

you can use rxjs delay pipe:

```
getMethod(): Observable {
  return of(2)
}
const delayedMethod = getMethod.pipe(delay(1000))
delayedClicks.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Doesn't this just delays the response? I mean, it doesn't actually delays the observable subscription, only holds the response for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise & async-await to achieve this. Check below code

```js
  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

await sleep(2000) // This will give 2 seconds delay
```

Comment: using promises i can do that but using delay i am trying to find a solution