# How to get buttons and apply an event to them

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am using this code to add a function when buttons are clicked, but it's not working.

```
function onClick(){
    console.log("Button pressed.");
    localStorage.counter = ++counter;
    console.log(counter);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange");
    console.log(buttons);
    console.log("buttons.length:")
    console.log(buttons.length);
    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].onclick = onClick();
        console.log("Event added")
    }
}, false);
```

When page loads I only get this in the console:
[Chrome Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzF3o.png)

Also nothing happens when I click on the buttons. If I debug it with breakpoints in chrome the output will change and it will say that the buttons is empty.

EDIT: The problem is that its not even entering for loop.

EDIT2: The buttons don't appear when load event is called. window.addEventListener('load') is executing too early

[Load is called before the page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRgqA.png)

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Do the buttons have the classes listed in `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: It doesn't enter into loop because `buttons.length` is zero. You are probably targeting wrong classnames in `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: @OzgurSar look at the picture I posted, it's not empty it has 2 buttons in it

Comment: @Peca21 Sorry I didn't notice that section of the image as buttons.length was already showing 0. Do you have any script that modifies the DOM after the page has initially loaded?

Comment: @OzgurSar Website is from my work so I can't show it but yes the things are loading AFTER the page has been loaded.

Comment: @Peca21 please try to run your javascript at the footer and after all other scripts have run.

Comment: @OzgurSar how do I run it after every other script?

Comment: @Peca21 I mean place it in the footer after all the other javascript calls.

Comment: @OzgurSar I am using tampermonkey, I have no access to the website source. I don't know how to place it at the end with tampermonkey.

Comment: @Peca21 Please check my answer. I wrapped your code inside a `setInterval()` function to make sure it is executed 100 miliseconds after the page has loaded. You can try to increase the waiting time in case 100ms is not enough.

Comment: @OzgurSar the problem is its not consistent, sometimes it loads buttons after 1 second sometimes after 10 seconds. ALso I sometimes press the button after less than 10 seconds so i can't use set interval.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling onClick while attacching click handler. You just have to provide the function instead of calling it.

HTML:

```
  <button class="v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange">
    Test1
  </button>
  <button class="v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange">
    Test2
  </button>
```

JS:

```
function onClick(){
    console.log("Button pressed.");
    localStorage.counter = ++counter;
    console.log(counter);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange");
    console.log("buttons.length:")
    console.log(buttons.length);
    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].onclick = onClick;
        console.log("Event added")
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: The problem is that its not even entering for loop.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/borezec/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is the working example, let me know if it is still not working

Comment: load event is called to early, even before the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onClick(){
    console.log("Button pressed.");
    // localStorage.counter = ++counter;
    // console.log(counter);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange");
    console.log("buttons.length:")
    console.log(buttons.length);
    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          onClick();
        });
        console.log("Event added")
    }
}, false);
```

```html
  <button class="v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange">
    Test1
  </button>
  <button class="v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange">
    Test2
  </button>
```

Comment: The problem is that its not even entering for loop.

Comment: @Peca21 then you do something else wrong, because as you can see in the snippet, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that your script runs after all other script has executed you can make use of `setInterval()`. I set it to 100 miliseconds (which you can see at the bottom. So, your code will wait 100ms after the page has loaded and will then execute.

As proposed in other answers, you should not call onClick when assigning it to an element's event handler. So, I changed that as well.

```
function onClick(){
    console.log("Button pressed.");
    localStorage.counter = ++counter;
    console.log(counter);
}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var i = setInterval(function ()
  {
    clearInterval(i);
    console.log("Loaded");
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange");
    console.log(buttons);
    console.log("buttons.length:")
    console.log(buttons.length);
    var i;
    for(i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].onclick = onClick;
        console.log("Event added")
    }
  }, 100);

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

I used this to create a sort of a sleep function

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

And then just checked for a button to appear every half a second like this

```
do {
   buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("v-btn v-btn--small theme--dark orange");
   await delay(500);
} while(!(buttons.length == 2));
```

From: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

[Full Code Here](https://pastebin.com/L0bZ2HhM)