# Run loading screen for custom time and remove it

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I need to run the loading screen for **10 seconds** and then **remove** it. And I also tried with setTimeOut but it's not working as I needed. I searched for many tutorials and they only teach how to add a loading animation until the page loads. Please show me the way seniors

```js
const loading = document.querySelector(".loader");
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  loading.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Comment: try with this [code] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-JavaScript-to-load-a-webpage-after-5-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you are a planning to wait for the timeout to end and the subsequent code to get executed only after that. You can also hide the content from getting displayed for that much time (for example 10 seconds) and only after timer completes will the content be shown and loader will be hidden.

Note: Any asynchronous code you write is taken out of the normal execution flow and if your further logic (synchronous or asynchronous) should get executed only after completion of that async task then you **have** to wait using `await` keyword.

```js
const loading = document.querySelector(".loader");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");
content.style.display = "none";
window.addEventListener('load', async function() {
  await setTimeout(()=>{
    content.style.display = "block";
    loading.style.display = "none";    
  }, 10000)
});
```

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe setTimeout shall work fine here.
If only you want to block further code execution before loading end, you may use async/await, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line).

```js
const loading = document.querySelector(".loader");
const content = document.querySelector(".countdown");
let countdown = 10

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.style.display = "none";
  }, 10000)

  setInterval(() =>{
    countdown--
    content.innerHTML = countdown
  },1000)
});
```

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="countdown">10</div>
```