# how to hide a div on page load with a 5 second delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

so what i want to do is to hide the element for the first 5 seconds the i want the element to show after 5 secs of page load
i have tried many methods but nothing worked yet

here is my code:

```
 <div id="main_sec_2"></div>
```

css

```
#main_sec_2{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

js

```
        function delay () {
        setTimeout( function() { 
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('main_sec_2').style.display = 'inline-block';
}
;}, 500 );
    }
```

Comment: why not use css-animation?

Comment: Your code has many issues. First, you shouldn't execute a function inside of a function, 2. 5 seconds is 5000 not 500, 3. you haven't executed the delay function, 4. please use a code beautifier. On top of this, please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript, then your JavaScript code isn't working for a few reasons.

---

Below is some working JavaScript code. (The explanation is below it.)

```js
function delay() {
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("main_sec_2").style.display = "inline-block";
    }, 5000);
  }
}

delay();
```

```css
#main_sec_2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_sec_2">Division!</div>
```

<sup>Text in `div` used for visualisation purposes.</sup>

---

The reason this code works is:

1. The `setTimeout` delay is set to `5000`, not `500`. The reason this works is because the timeout is measured in milliseconds, so `5000` milliseconds is the same as `5` seconds.
2. *(Maybe)* The `window.onload` function has the `setTimeout` inside of it.  This means that when the `onload` function is called, the `setTimeout` will automatically start.
3. *(Maybe)* The `delay` function is being called. <sub>*Note that this may be because the OP didn't include the call.*</sub>

---

In conclusion, you can use JavaScript or CSS for this issue, but this solution fixes the issue the JavaScript way.

Comment: thanks for answering my question.

but still, I have some issues 
like when I want to add it to another div in the same inline list it fails

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `css-animation` which does not require JS.

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: randomName;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes randomName {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}



/* for visualisation purpose only */
div {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_sec_2"></div>
```

Comment: I want it to "really" be not there for some resizing issues