# TypeScript: How to make code wait / sleep for few seconds before next step?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function which needs to check a value. If it doesn't exist then it needs to wait and then call itself again. Below is the code. But it doesn't seem to wait for 5 sec but keeps executing without waiting it seems. How do I ix it?

```
  loadAPI(status: string) {
   .....

          if (this.result === "done") {
            .....
          }
          else
          {
            this.sleep(5000);
            loadAPI(this.status);
          }
    }});
  }

  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

Comment: `this.sleep` is async (resolving when the setTimeout gets popped; `loadAPI` needs to wait for the promise to resolve, and then fire itself again

Comment: You don't do anything with the promise sleep returns...

Comment: so your call stack ends up looking like `loadApi -> sleep -> loadApi -> sleep` to infinity with `sleep` resolving randomly in there whenever it can get in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited you example code using vanilla js and async/await,
you can implement it in Typescript as well

```
class App 
{
    async loadAPI(status) {
        console.log(status)
        
        if (false) {
         
        }
        else
        {
            await this.sleep(2000);
            this.loadAPI(status);
        }
    }

    sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}

(new App).loadAPI('loadAPI called')
```