# Execute Javascript onclick after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

On my website I use a modal popup for visitors to enter some info before they can enter the website. I use a script found [here](http://codeissue.com/articles/a04daf3210c8b0a/cross-browser-modal-popup-using-javascript-jquery) which I really appreciate because it seems to work on every browser (also the ones without position:fixed support).

So when you visit my website you click on this link and because of the

```
onclick="ShowModalPopup('dvPopup'); return false;"
```

the window pops up - works perfectly.

However, I want the window to popup automatically say 3 seconds after the website is loaded. I would like to use this script for the popup so I'm looking for a way to execute the onclick after 3 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Just a note: if the window.open is not invoked by user action the popup blocker will engage the window, therefore the Mike Brant code is the correct one, a function that you need to apply somewhere, instead of the others guys trying to open a popup in the document.ready or load event.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myLink').click();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        setTimeout(function () {
            ShowModalPopup('dvPopup');
        },3000);
    }); 
</script>
```

The script will count 3 seconds after the page is rendered and will run the ShowModalPopup('dvPopup')

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQUery you can simply trigger the call on document load like this:

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        ShowModalPopup('dvPopup');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
                  setTimeout(foo, 3000); 

                };

function foo()
{
 ShowModalPopup('dvPopup');
}
```