# In JavaScript how to add delay in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, time, delay

In JavaScript how can i add delay to JavaScript loop
In this below code

```
snakeclass.prototype.start = function() {
    while(1){
        if(this.collision()){
            console.log("game over");
            break;
        }

        this.movesnake();

        // delay here by 300 miliseconds
    }
};
```

how can i use Set Timeout function here;

Comment: Do you mean, delay the whole while loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work. Your browser is just going to freeze up if you do this:

```
while (1) {}
```

You can however use a setInterval.

```
snakeclass.prototype.start = function() {
    var interval;
    var doo = function () {
        if(this.collision()){
            console.log("game over");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        this.movesnake();
    }.bind(this); // bind this so it can be accessed again inside the function
    doo();
    timeout = setInterval(doo, 300);
};
```

Comment: Hmm, try refreshing the page.