# Timer with new Date() in js

Tags: javascript

I got 5 sprites( 5 blocks, each next smaller than previous).
And they drawing too fast. how to right use new Date(), getMilliseconds or other methods for timer that would draw with some delay?

For ex.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
    xxx.drawImage(sprite, i, etc);
}
```

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Perhaps not related to your question, but you should use `var` in declaring variables: `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: decl what? dunno that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` to set a timer. But you should notice a subtle difference between these 2 functions due to single threaded nature of javascript. Let's look at the example:

```
setTimeout(function test() {
   //your code
   setTimeout(test, 100);
}, 100);

setInterval(function() {
     //your code
}, 100);
```

These 2 blocks of code appear to be the same, but that's not the case due to single-threaded nature of javascript.

- With `setInterval()`: if your code is busy executing and takes long time to complete. The next intervals **may fire while your code is still executing** and these intervals will be queued up. In the end, you may end up with some handlers running in succession **without any delay**
- With `setTimeout()`: the next interval is only set to be fired **when you're current code has finished**. This guarantee that the next execution will never be less than the interval (100 in this case), only equal to or longer.

Comment: thats would not work in a cycle 

    function main() {
        setTimeout(function test() {
     console.log('test');
     setTimeout(test, 1000);
        }, 1000);

        requestAnimFrame(main);
    }

timeout executes 1 time after 1000ms and then function executes withiout delay... sorry for that mess... cant answer, just comment(

Comment: @Rss_game_dev: you should not do it like this. Try:  `function main() { setTimeout(function test() { console.log('test'); requestAnimFrame(variable); setTimeout(test, 1000); }, 1000); }`. I assume that the `requestAnimFrame` is your logic to draw image, change the parameter to another name (`variable` as in the example) to avoid name conflicting with the `main` function

Comment: I just tried to do ur code but RequestAnimationFrame in brackets needs the name of function which would periodically execute. so function main() { RequestAnimationFrame(main) } thats works but how in this function call 'test' each time after 1000ms. not once

Comment: @Rss_game_dev: you should create another function and call it `requestAnimFrame(variable);` (in this case I define the function as `variable`)