# Simulate a timed async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sleep

I'm trying to simulate an async callback, that does something in a set number of seconds. I want these to all log at the same time, 3 seconds from when they are triggered. Right now they log consecutively 3 seconds after each other. The sleep functions are blocking the whole script from running. Any idea why?

```js
function sleep(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

var same = function(string, callback) {
  new sleep(3000);
  return callback(string);
}

same("same1", function(string) {
  console.log(string);
});
same("same2", function(string) {
  console.log(string);
});
same("same3", function(string) {
  console.log(string);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: *"Any idea why?"* Because JavaScript is single threaded and you are continuously running the loop.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded.  You can't do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelixKling single-threaded yes!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to schedule something for a future time.

Also, `setTimeout()` is async, your looping is not.

```
var same = function(str, callback){
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(str);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Note: you cannot return a value from the async callback because it's async.  The function `same()` completes and returns long before the callback is actually called.

Answer (score 10):

With ES6, you can use the following technique based on an helper delay function:

```
const delay = async (delay = 1000, callback = () => {}) => {        

  const delayPromise = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
  await delayPromise(delay)

  callback()
}

const funcCallback = () => { console.info('msg WITH delay > 2') }

delay(5000, funcCallback)
console.info('Instant msg > 1')
```

Comment: Why would I want to make use of a promise here instead of simply using setTimeout()? What are the advantages of using a promise here?