# how to execute script after certain interval of time

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the twitter widget to display my timeline on a simple webpage. But what I really want to achieve is , whenever I tweet something from twitter ,I want to see it on the webpage I have created without being refreshed. So what I want to do is call the script after every 3secs or so. Please let me know how to do it.

Here's the code for the html page I have done.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Twitter Feed Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<p>Testing how to get the the twitter feeds to webpage</p>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/happyman_mayur" data-widget-id="509282432604844032">Tweets by @happyman_mayur</a>
<script>
!function(d,s,id){
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
if(!d.getElementById(id))
{
js=d.createElement(s);
js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Comment: `setTimeout()` would seem appropriate here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

Comment: The problem so far with the answers is that while they mention `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, the script in the question is just the script that is embedding the widget. You don't want to put that code in `setInterval` because it won't work. It is checking that there is no existing element with id "twitter-wjs", if it does, it does nothing.

Comment: Twitter widgets poll for updates automatically every 1 second as long as you have not defined a tweet limit. Are you not seeing it refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better, Twitter-specific way, but the simplest way to do so in Javascript is to use the `setInterval` function.

```
setInterval(function () {
    // Your code here
}, 3000)
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Comment: Not able to get it work, can you try it on JSFiddle and help me please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqsqzxu3/ As @Cory pointed out, the code simply creates the element if it isn't already there, so it requires a bit of fiddling. However, he also said that there's an automatic refresh, so maybe this isn't necessary? EDIT: tis solution won't work because it doesn't clear the old widget. I'll fix it if it turns out that Twitter's widget doesn't auto-refresh.

Answer (score 0):

With setInterval or setTimeout (recursive);

You should visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

But be careful to clearInterval o clearTimeout on unload