# show div after x seconds or when click

Tags: javascript, html

I've got two divs like:

```
<div id="h1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="h2" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and

```
<a onclick="showh1()">h1</a>
<a onclick="showh2()">h2</a>
```

and this javascript for choose one div to be shown

```
function showh1() {
                 document.getElementById('h1').style.display = "block";
                }
function showh2() {
                 document.getElementById('h2').style.display = "block";
                }
```

But I'd like to show div h1 after x seconds or when the users clicks to show one of two divs. How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a [`timing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript) Have you even Googled “javascript delay”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After X seconds:

```
function showh1() {
  document.getElementById("h1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showh1()", x*1000); // after x secs
```

Call function on click:

```
<a onclick="showh1()">h1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you it works nice! But, now how can I do to hide after 1 second when mouse is over a certain div?

Comment: `setTimeout("showh1()", x*1000);` ► Not sure about using a function reference as a string  never seen that before, why not use ► `setTimeout(showh1, x*1000);` or when/if more calls are needed wrap it `setTimeout(function(){showh1();}, x*1000);`

Comment: Its old school style of coding baby :P

Comment: @Manikiran: lol :) Fair enough :) I just never seen it before or could get jsFiddle to execute it. If it works it works :)

Comment: @FacuSubiabre Here's your required code: `document.getElementById("h1").onmouseover=setTimeout(function (){document.getElementById("h1").style.visibility = "hidden";}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

when the window loads, set both display to hide and then set a timeout with javascript to run the code to set the display to not hide.