# How to make a function delay 5 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make a function to display after 5 or 6 seconds

```
    function a() {
alert("after 5 seconds");
}

a();
```

Comment: `setTimeout(a, 5000)`

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like setTimeout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script after specific delay using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/execute-script-after-specific-delay-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use all JS timers that you want.

setTimeout/setInterval, etc.

```
var duration = 5000; #in ms, miliseconds. 5000 = 5s

function delayedAlert() {
  window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 5000);
}

function slowAlert() {
  alert('That was really slow!');
}
```

Look more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: You should not answer a duplicate. Its a bad practice

Comment: What is duplicate? I took the mdn example and adapted to him o.O

Just being pragmatic, seriously?

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I think he means don't answer a duplicate question, not that your answer is a duplicate.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons ahn, okay dudes, i was writing before him post, sry

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre it doesn't bother me, just explaining what he meant :-)

Comment: A duplicate is a post that has been asked on the portal before. When you come across a question that is basic question, there is a high possibility that its already been asked. Such posts have many answers and discussion. You should look for such posts and share their link instead.

Comment: Thank you, by now I will take care about that.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh i was looking for different method to solve that problem, i got it thank you and as you  said i won't post duplicate question again. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```js
function delayer(ms){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve();
    }, ms)
  })
}

async function myFunction(){  // Function Must be async.
  console.log("First Console")
  await delayer(3000);    // This Will Stop The Code For 3 Seconds
  console.log("Second Console After 3 Seconds")
}


myFunction()
```