# Moving circle in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to move circle up, next right then down. I made 3 functions: `up`, `right` and `down`. I use them, but they are going parallel. I want that if first function will end, then second will start and so on..
Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var progress = 0;
function up(){
    console.log('up');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(300, 300 - progress, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(up);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last up')
    }
}
function right(){
    console.log('right');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(300 + progress, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last right')
    }
}
function down(){
    console.log('down');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(400, 200 + progress, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last down')
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(up);
window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
window.requestAnimationFrame(down);
```

*---------------------------------*

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

*------------------------------------*

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

**Console output:**

> first up  stack.js:8:5 first right  stack.js:22:5 first down 
>   stack.js:36:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first
>   up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5
>   first right stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 first right
>   stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first
>   up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5
>   first right stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 first right
>   stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first
>   up  stack.js:8:5 first right stack.js:22:5 first up  stack.js:8:5 last
>   up  stack.js:18:9 first right stack.js:22:5 last right  stack.js:32:9
>   first right stack.js:22:5 last right  stack.js:32:9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script after specific delay using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/execute-script-after-specific-delay-using-javascript)

Comment: you want to callback it one after one finishes right?

Comment: the4kman-I tried use delay and it works fine but it is not satisfy me

Comment: Kresimir Pendic- that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call `window.requestAnimationFrame(up);` at the bottom, and then call the others when `progress` gets over `100`. Like this:

```
function up(){
    //...
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(up);
    }else{
       progress = 0;
       console.log('last up');
       window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
    }
}
```

This would be the complete code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var progress = 0;
function up(){
    console.log('up');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(300, 300 - progress, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(up);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last up');
        window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
    }
}
function right(){
    console.log('right');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(300 + progress, 200, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(right);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last right');
        window.requestAnimationFrame(down);
    }
}
function down(){
    console.log('down');
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    c.beginPath();
    progress += 3;
    c.arc(400, 200 + progress, 50, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    if(progress < 100){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(down);
    }else{
        progress = 0;
        console.log('last down');
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(up);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

*Also available here: https://jsfiddle.net/kvmt6ru9/*