# Can't delay using data in Vue for after getting value from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to compare string that I get from firebase in document.check1 with some strings (written hard in function below) and show Content. I know how to call it out in button but I want to check it right after entering the page - not after clicking. When I try to do it - I get error that it has no value. How can I make it "wait" for the data to collect automaticaly?

```
 <template>
         <router-link to="/konto">Back</router-link>
         <div v-if="document">        
           <div>
             <span>1:</span>
             {{ document.check1 }},
             <span>2:</span>
             {{ document.check2 }},
             <span>3:</span>
             {{ document.check3.length }}
           </div>
         </div>
         <button v-if="itWorkOk" @click="documentCheck">Show Content after finding result</button>
          <div v-if="isOther">
           <p>Content</p>
         </div>
 </template>
 
 <script>
 import getUser from "../composables/getUser";
 import getDocument from "../composables/getDocument";
 import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
 
 export default {
   props: ["id", "document"],
   setup(props) {
     const { error, document } = getDocument("AllData", props.id);
     const { user } = getUser();
 
     const itWorkOk = ref(true);
     const result1 = ref("");
     const isOther = ref("");
 
     const documentCheck = async () => {
       const isItOk = document.value.check1
       if (isItOk == "Result One") {
         result1.value = true;
         itWorkOk.value = false;
       } else {
         isOther.value = true; 
         itWorkOk.value = false; 
       }
     };
 
     return {
       error, user, document, documentCheck, result1, isOther, itWorkOk,
     };
   },
 };
 </script>
```

The error (when I put function to call immediately):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.value is null
```

The getDocument code:

```
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const getDocument = (collection, id) => {

  const document = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  let documentRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

  const unsub = documentRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
    if(doc.data()) {
        document.value = {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
        error.value = null
    } else {
        error.value = "Document does not exist"
    }
    
  }, err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    error.value = 'Couldn't get the document'
  })

  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => unsub());
  });

  return { error, document }
}

export default getDocument
```

Comment: Can you show us the getDocument code, please?

Comment: @GlebKostyunin sure, I've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used setTimeout(function () { methotToCall(); }, 1000); thanks to this thread - stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/… and it "worked" so I'm gonna close this one. I'm sure this is not the right method, but it will work for a time. Thank's for help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to fetch the Firestore data in one of the [lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram) before the component is mounted, for example [`created`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#created) or [`mounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted).

In the lifecycle hook, you asynchronously read the data from Firestore and compare the result to the desired values.

Comment: Maybe it's one of the options? The result matters. I think there should be some other way to maybe delay function to use/compare this data once it's retrieved.

Comment: @AdamGrzywacz Did you try it?

Comment: I used   setTimeout(documentCheck(), 10000);   but I get the same error. Like it's using function at start but only show the result after delay.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` is not a good idea IMHO. You should correctly manage the asynchronous character of the Firestore methods.

Comment: I would be happy to. Any more specific direction? ^^'

Comment: I used    setTimeout(function () { methotToCall(); }, 1000);   thanks to this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/execute-script-after-specific-delay-using-javascript?rq=1   and it "worked" so I'm gonna close this one. I'm sure this is not the right method, but it will work for a time. Thank's for help :)